# Is it me or is it crazy that 70% of the questions on the main page were downvoted at least once?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

It's me or is it crazy that 70% of the [questions on the main page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) were downvoted once? I am not sure why this is OK, I think there's a serial downvoter who just downvotes every question for the sake of downvoting, and that's not OK.

Comment: On what are you basing your figure of 70%?

Comment: I think the OP meant 70% of the questions in the questions page (not home page) @MichaelHarvey

Comment: @DialFrost - on the All Questions page right now I can see 47 questions, and of these 28 have a vote level of under 0 so that makes 28/47 which is 59% in round numbers. This might change from day to day.

Comment: I think a figure of 70% for questions which are low quality or duplicates is not unusual in any way.

Comment: I saw this as well and was going to bring it up here till I saw your post. I do feel like somebody just serially downvotes questions, and answers as well.

Comment: Why don't I seem to ever see questions on Meta deploring excessive upvotes? If it is theorised that some, at least of new-question downvotes are the result of malice, cruelty, or spite, then cannot at least some upvotes come from their positive counterparts? Or, as I commented below, from a misguided attempt to correct some perceived 'imbalance'?

Comment: ... and, developing this thought further, might they not cancel each other out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks, your intuition was correct. Moderators can't see more than regular users do in this case, but I've escalated the issue to staff, they've found a pattern and corrected these votes where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I was tempted to upvote questions with only 1 downvote.

Comment: @Sayaman - you should upvote questions that you think are deserving of that because they have some merit, and downvote those that are clearly lacking in merit. Issuing blanket upvotes because you think downvotes are silly or bad is not what you should be doing.

Comment: Do the invalidated votes go further back? I saw that a large number of questions a week ago (July 5th?) scored -1 or less (15 in a row excluding 0 score questions).

Comment: @Laurel yes. I checked the author's reputation history and they got a downvote on June 20, and that question is now back at +0/-0.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me, or are questions on meta being serially downvoted as well?

Comment: @DialFrost - poor quality questions (e.g. whining about downvotes) appear on meta as well as the main site. Excessive preoccupation with votes, rep, etc, is to be deplored.